# Mate-weather applet stopped working

Tags: mate, applet, weather

My mate-weather applet suddenly stopped working. Have tried other locations, none work. Has anyone else encountered this and do you know of a fix?

Seen on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, MATE 1.18 and on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, MATE 1.22.

Comment: FYI: Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS being a flavor of Ubuntu had only 3 years of supported life (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) which ended 2019-April. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server (no desktop) or Desktop (Unity 7) have 5 years of supported life and are still supported. Refer release notes, or use `ubuntu-support-status` or your own system to confirm this is the case. I suggest you move to a supported release of Ubuntu-MATE for security reasons, unless you're off-line or are aware of risks.  https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/ubuntu-mate-16-04-lts-reaches-end-of-life/19425

Comment: @guiverc really it happens on 20.04 LTS too.

Comment: The backend here is  aviationweather.gov . So please STOP closing this question as duplicate because it does not use openweather !!! And STOP closing it as off-topic because It exists in all Ubuntu versions !!!

Comment: @N0rbert my comment is FYI as I don't vote EOL on partially-supported (flavor LTS) releases.  I think the FYI is worthwhile as so many unofficial sites still say flavors come with 5 years (as main Ubuntu does) which is & has always been untrue (with minor exceptions, eg. Kylin on 16.04 had 5 years sponsored by Canonical)

Comment: @guiverc OK, thank you :)

Comment: Please reopen. This is absolutely different issue!!!

Comment: @AlBrundage see updated answer. I prepared one line binary patch.

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2020-06-24: problem is solved on server-side. No additional manual actions required.**

---

This is aviationweather.gov server side issue, which now is in the works.

The Ubuntu MATE community [also knows about](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/clock-applet-has-stopped-showing-weather-information/22013) the issue, the pull request [is prepared](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/clock-applet-has-stopped-showing-weather-information/22013/4).

Please wait for resolution.

Note: all current Ubuntu MATE versions are affected. And not only MATE, as the aviationweather.gov is used by some other Ubuntu projects.

---

For those who do not want to wait there are two possible solutions.

- Patch the MATE Weather library on binary level with single command below:

  - 64 bit

    `sudo sed -i 's|https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam|https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver1_3/httpparam\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0|' $(readlink -f /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmateweather.so.1)`
  - 32 bit

    `sudo sed -i 's|https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam|https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver1_3/httpparam\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0|' $(readlink -f /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmateweather.so.1)`

  Note: to revert the patch one can reinstall the corresponding package with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libmateweather1`.
- Use My Weather Indicator applet from [Atareo PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eatareao/+archive/ubuntu/atareao/+packages?field.name_filter=my-weather-indicator&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=) by one of the following methods:

  - by adding PPA

    ```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install my-weather-indicator
    ```

  - by downloading package manually:

    ```
    cd ~/Downloads
    wget https://launchpad.net/~atareao/+archive/ubuntu/atareao/+files/my-weather-indicator_0.9.4-0extras19.10.09_all.deb
    sudo apt-get install ./my-weather-indicator_0.9.4-0extras19.10.09_all.deb
    ```

  and then find the application in the *Applications → Accessories → My-Weather-Indicator* and set settings for it.
  Optionally you can add it to autostart by placing the corresponding desktop-file in the correct directory:

  ```
  mkdir -p ~/.config/autostart
  cat << EOF > ~/.config/autostart/my-weather-indicator.desktop
  [Desktop Entry]
  Type=Application
  Exec=/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/bin/my-weather-indicator
  Hidden=false
  X-MATE-Autostart-enabled=true
  Name=My Weather Indicator
  EOF
  ```